# How to resolve circular dependency in a c++ game?

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-development

I am currently working on a game, and I am trying to implement a simple collision feature in my game. I currently have a `world` class that stores a list of all my `player`s. I wanted to give the player ability to shoot bullets and detect collision, but that will make player need information about `world` since it needs to access these information stored in the world.

In this case, should I use forward declaration and keep the circular dependency, or should I try to resolve it? A lot of posts online say that there shouldn't be circular dependency and that you can solve it easily with better design, but I wasn't able to find a single post that offered a good resolution.

How should I resolve this, and what do game engines usually do?

Comment: Forward declaration and provide the definitions after all the declarations.

Comment: There is no one answer, programming is creative task. Circular dependecies come with issues, but other solutions will have other issues. If you don't have a clear vision of advantages and disadvanteges of each, I would stick to something you understand.

Comment: Circular dependencies in header files are totally unrelated to the type of program you're developing. And there must be several thousand of duplicates here on this site you you look around a little.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with circular references as long as you have an ordered shutdown story that prevents one instance of a class from accessing a deleted instance of another class.